# Statement could not be executed (HY000 - 2006 - MySQL server has gone away) (Amazon RDS DB)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

In some case I have this exception, I'am using Amazon server, and amazon RBS DB mysql db service. I can not resolve issue, because it throws only sometimes.

Comment: it could be that your max_allowed_packet is too small, you can try setting it to a higher value and monitor the server to see if that helps

Comment: I checked everything in amazone documentation and try to fix with their suggestion, but I steel have the same problem.

Comment: That's fine, but have you tried to make the max_allowed_packet bigger? That seems to be one of the most common causes for your particular error.

Comment: Yes I tried. I tried everything in this page. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-sql-server-gone-away/

Comment: There are *two* settings for `max_allowed_packet` -- one in the RDS parameter group, an another one on your client library.  **These two values must be set the same**, so you'll need to set it on your side as well as on RDS.  Mention what client library you are using, if you need help finding the client-side setting.

Comment: Thank You for response  @Michael-sqlbot, we ara using php, how can I configure it?

Comment: On the PHP side, it turns out, I have no idea.  I would have thought it would be part of the DSN, but I can't find any evidence of this in the documentation.  The correct solution is for both client and server values to be in sync, but it will also work around your issue if you simply increase the value on the server, in the RDS Parameter Group.

Comment: I already increase value in parameter group, but steal have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue. When my process starting it adding another process to queue and that process never ended. Now I add all that part in try catch block, and when catching mysql error I start mysql process.